# Link static cell to function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

In my account view scene I want to able the users the capability to send us an email, and,  is it a good approach to fire directly to the email app when the users tap the cell? otherwise to include a button with an IBfunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MessageUI` framework to send an email straight from your app.

This gives you the ability to pre-populate content and what you want to send. Documentation for the framework is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/) and you can find an example in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html).